# Unidentified index after a command

Tags: php, forms, session, post

my S_SESSION['carrier'] and $_SESSION['payment'] is not unidentified after my update command, i have no idea why, but before i press the button, it works, i tried echoing the values and it works, but after sending the command, it gets unidentified.

```
$_SESSION['carrier'] = $_POST['carrier'];
    $_SESSION['payment'] = $_POST['payment'];
    echo $_SESSION['payment'];
    echo $_SESSION['carrier'];

    if(isset($_GET['command']) && $_GET['command']=='update'){


        $first_name=$_SESSION['first_name'];
        $email=$_SESSION['email'];
        $home_address=$_SESSION['home_address'];
        $mobile_phone=$_SESSION['mobile_phone'];
        $carrier=$_SESSION['carrier'];
        $payment=$_SESSION['payment'];
        $track = "";
        $status = "On Process";
        $result=mysql_query("insert into customers values('','$first_name','$email','$home_address','$mobile_phone','$carrier','$payment', '$track', '$status')");

    echo $payment;
    echo $carrier;

        $customerid=mysql_insert_id();
        date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Hong_Kong");
        $date=date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
        $result=mysql_query("insert into orders values('','$date','$customerid')");
        $orderid=mysql_insert_id();


        $qry="SELECT * FROM shipping WHERE ship_name='{$_SESSION['carrier']}'";
        $result= @mysql_query($qry);
        while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 

        $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
        for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
            $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
            $q=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'];
            $price=get_prod_price($pid); // this one yung mag iinsert ng total sa database.
            $huhu=$price+$row['ship_price'];

                if($row['ship_price'] > 0){
                mysql_query("insert into order_detail values ($orderid,$pid,$q,$huhu)");
                    }
                else{
                mysql_query("insert into order_detail values ($orderid,$pid,$q,$price)");
                    }
            }
        }

        //header('refresh: 0; url=userorder.php'); // to be redirected
        exit(); // para mawala ang puta, tumigil ang script.
    }


    ?>
```

In those lines of code above, the $_SESSION wont work.

but here.

```
<form name="form1" onsubmit="return validate()">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="terms" />  I agree to the <a href="../terms.php" target="_blank"><u><b>terms of service</u></b></a> and adhere to them unconditionally.<br><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="command" />
                <table border="0" cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="1px" style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:11px; background-color:#E1E1E1" width="500px" class="CSSTableGenerator">
                        <?php
                            if(is_array($_SESSION['cart'])){
                                echo '<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-weight:bold"><td></td><td>Name</td><td>Price</td><td>Qty</td><td>Amount</td></tr>';
                                $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
                                for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
                                    $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
                                    $q=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'];
                                    $pname=get_product_prod_name($pid);
                                    if($q==0) continue;
                            ?>

                                    <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><td><?php echo $i+1?></td><td><?php echo $pname?></td>
                                    <td>₱<?php echo number_format(get_prod_price($pid),2)?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $q?></td>                    
                                    <td>₱<?php echo number_format((get_prod_price($pid)*$q),2)?></td>
                                    </tr>
                            <?php                   
                                }

                                $qry="SELECT * FROM shipping WHERE ship_name='{$_SESSION['carrier']}'";
                                $result= @mysql_query($qry);
                                while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
                                $tot = get_order_total();
                                $amounttot = $tot+$row['ship_price'];
                            ?>

                                <tr><td></td><td colspan="3"><b>Sub Total: </td>

                                    <td>₱<?php echo number_format($tot,2); ?></b></td></tr>

                                <tr><td></td><td colspan='3'><b>
                                <?php 
                                if($row['ship_price']>0){
                                echo "Shipment Option: ".$_SESSION['carrier']."<td>₱ ".$row['ship_price']."</td>";
                                echo "<tr><td></td><td colspan='3'><b>Order Total: </td>

                                    <td><b>₱";
                                echo number_format($amounttot,2);
                                echo "</b></td></tr>";
                                    }

                                else{
                                echo "Shipment Option: ".$_SESSION['carrier']."<td>₱ ".$row['ship_price']."</td>";
                                echo "<tr><td></td><td colspan='3'><b>Order Total: </td>

                                    <td><b>₱";
                                echo number_format($amounttot,2);
                                echo "</b></td></tr>";
                                }
                            }

                                ?></b></td></tr>
                            <tr><td colspan="5"><div align="right">
                                <input type="button" value="View Shopping Cart" onclick="window.location='shoppingcart.php'">
                                <input type="button" value="Change Shipping Options" onclick="window.location='shipping.php'">
                                <input type="submit" disabled="disable" value="Place Order" id="submitBtn"/></td></tr>

                            <?php
                            }
                        ?>

                </table>
                <!--<table>
                        <tr><td><input type="button" value="View Shopping Cart" onclick="window.location='shoppingcart.php?'"><input type="button" value="Change Shipping Options" onclick="window.location='shipping.php?'"><input type="submit" value="Place Order"/></td></tr>
                </table> -->
    </form>
```

it works fine on this one, i dont know what's wrong, please help. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `isset` and it will catch your unidentified index error.

```
 if (isset($_POST['FORM NAME ON PREVIOUS PAGE'])){
        $_SESSION['carrier'] = $_POST['carrier'];
        $_SESSION['payment'] = $_POST['payment'];
    }
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have value in your input named command: so try

```
<input type="hidden" name="command" value="update"/>
```

Comment: i do. i have this script. `function validate(){
  var f=document.form1;
  f.command.value='update';
  f.submit();
  alert("Order submitted");
 }`

Comment: Oh that's not that case. What is the error passed from server?

Comment: `print_r($_SESSION)` and then verify if there payment and carrier set or not.